# Flutter ListView wrong State matching for StatefulWidget items

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working with `ListView` and encountering an issue with it when its items are `StatefulWidget`.

For example, each widget has its own `countdownTime` saved in its State. When I insert FIRST a new widget to the list, the new **State** belongs to the wrong widget (**it must belong to the first instead of the last item**). It seems the deactivate-dispose state matching process got a problem. I tried adding `key` to them but it acted stranger as it disposes and recreated all widget items, resulting in all the countdowns reset.

It took me 2 days to research more about StatefulWidget and ListView but I couldn't help.

I created Dartpad here, please have a look if I did something wrong.
[Dartpad to the example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=66cbbaa98ef5c86b52984031bb2ff72e&null_safety=true)

Thank you so much!

Comment: remove `color` from `_MyStatefulState` and add it to `MyStatefulWidget`, something like: `class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
final color = generateRandomColor();
...`

Comment: Thanks. I know the State is very sensitive when we swap widget positions, it can be mismatching in that case but is there a way that this issue can be solved without moving the color out of the State?

Comment: It seems my example was too simple as I use a color constant in the State. I've changed the code in Dartpad, which actually was the State contains variable properties like countdownTime.
Although I add the new widget at first position but actually it reuses the wrong State

Comment: What you're saying is not clear. Please explain further.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html)

Add the **`AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`** mixin to your `State` of your `StatefulWidget` (Item widget), override the `wantKeepAlive` method and return `true`.

**What I solved:**

- New item will be added to the top of the list.
- Maintain state after scrolling

Your full (updated) dart:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String? title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> _widgets = [MyStatefulWidget()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.separated(
        itemCount: _widgets.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return _widgets[index];
        },
        reverse: true,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            // Insert first in the list, hope it's just need to rebuild only the first item, the remains are unchanged
            _widgets.add(MyStatefulWidget());
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          child: Text(
            'Press',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 24,
            ),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> createState');
    return _MyStatefulState();
  }
}

+class _MyStatefulState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin{
  StreamSubscription? countdownSubscription;
  int countdownTime = 30;

   @override
   bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initTimeoutUI();
  }

  void initTimeoutUI() {
    countdownSubscription = Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).asStream().listen((value) {
      if (countdownTime > 0) {
        setState(() {
          countdownTime--;
        });
      }
      initTimeoutUI();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    countdownSubscription?.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: Center(child: Text('countdown: $countdownTime')),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved my hard days. It worked!
I've checked and seen that the `reverse: true, shrinkWrap: true,` were for adding items to the top of the list, is it right?
And AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to maintain state after a long scrolling? I haven't checked what would happen with the states if the list is too long, but as you said some states would be lost if I scroll from the beginning to the end of the list, right?

Comment: Not actually, What I solved that is I wrote. It will maintain automatically even if long scroll. You must try it once. Kindly upvote and accept the answer if you found it useful.